# Algorithm to match people in a group based on who they are compatible with

Tags: python, algorithm, matching

I am trying to find the maximum matching in a group of people based on their compatibility. I was headed towards maximum cardinality matching on bipartite graphs when I realized I do not have 2 distinct groups.

Where I am at:

I have a list of their IDs: `[1, 8, 3, 15, 13, 21]`

I have a function called verify that will verify if 2 id's are compatible(there could be an odd number).

I then create a graph(dictionary) of the indices  each persons indices is compatible with:

```
    ids = [1, 8, 3, 15, 13, 21]
    l = len(ids)
    matches = {}
    for x in range(l):
        matches.setdefault(x,[])
        for y in range(l):
            if x != y:
                if verify(ids[x],ids[y]):
                    matches[x].append(y)
```

this produces:

```
{0: [3, 4, 5], 1: [2, 4, 5], 2: [1, 5], 3: [0, 4, 5], 4: [0, 1, 3], 5: [0, 1, 2, 3]}
```

Now I am unsure where to go from here or if I should be taking another direction.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?  Thanks

Comment: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching.html

Comment: Any experts here who can comment on matching based on minimum number of compatible parteners? i.e., match those people who have the minimum number of compatible partners and then gradually move upwards. Could this fall into a local minima?

Comment: What if the following were compatable:  {0: [4, 1], 1: [4], 2: [4], 3: [4], 4: [0, 1, 2, 3]}? {0, 1, 4} are all inter-compatable at the same time but that excludes {2, 4} as 2 is not compatible with 1 or 0? I am trying to get a better grasp of what you require.

Comment: I need maximum matches so it would be 3 for that one.  Was looking at Blossom as this is a non-bipartite graph but it is extremely complicated.  Currently I am building a recursive algorithm that cycles through each vertices(key) testing it against 1 pair from each other vertices group where they do not have that vertices in any already chosen edges their edge(key[0,1,2] if this makes sense? To find the maximum matches you find the largest number of edges you can make with no edges with the same vertices.

Comment: Also I am looking for more the logic than the actual code:)  These can be large datasets as well

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if you are trying to solve the [Stable marriage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem). I wrote a [Rosetta Code task](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) that has solutions in Python and other languages.

Comment: Thank you. I saw the smp but I do not believe it applies as it is a 2 groups(male and female) weighted directed graph where mine is a 1 group unweighted undirected graph? Each pair of people are either good to work with each other(both ways) or not. I am currently looking at the blossom algorithm

Comment: Could you not set the female preferences to mirror the male and apply the same algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me you're looking for the maximum clique in the graph, if you looking to find the biggest subset in a graph that all of the nodes are compatible (connected) with each other. for my knowledge this is np-complete problem, but maybe I got your question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I coded something up that works for your example:

```py
from typing import List, Dict, Optional, Tuple

compat = {0: [3, 4, 5], 1: [2, 4, 5], 2: [1, 5], 3: [0, 4, 5], 4: [0, 1, 3], 5: [0, 1, 2, 3]}

def match(compat: Dict[int, List[int]]) -> Optional[List[Tuple[int, int]]]:
    """Match compatible people."""
    c = sorted(compat.items())
    matched: Dict[int, int] = {}
    m = _match(c, matched)
    if m:
        m = {tuple(sorted([k, v])) for k, v in m.items()}
        m = sorted(m)
    return m

def _match(c, matched):
    """Match compatible people recursively."""
    if not c:
        return matched
    person, compat = c[0]
    if person in matched:
        return _match(c[1:], matched)
    else:
        for comp in compat:
            if not comp in matched:
                matched[person] = comp
                matched[comp] = person
                if _match(c[1:], matched):
                    return matched
                else:
                    del matched[person], matched[comp]
    return None

print(match(compat))     # [(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5)]
```

Comment: Thanks. This fails for me on some IE {0: [4], 1: [4], 2: [4], 3: [4], 4: [0, 1, 2, 3]}, it shows no matches when the maximum is 1.  What algorithm is this?

Comment: I took your question as needing solutions where **all** persons are matched, hence giving no matches for your new testcase. The algorithm is my own; you may call it the Paddy3118 algorithm. If you provide a sute of test cases and expected answers I could try and solve the extended problem with enough test data - with expected results, to better test it. An interesting problem.

Comment: All persons are perfect matching, im only interested in maximum matching. Sorry I did not see this post but I have it solved:)  Take a look and see if you can tell which algorithm it uses if it uses one..I have not been able to tell unless the poster came up with it, in that case, genious.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic that solved my code(have not taken the time to convert my code to a SO version:

It comes from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3303557/12941578

Given the adjacency matrix I posted(which is basically a set of edges but why convert):

`{0: [3, 4, 5], 1: [2, 4, 5], 2: [1, 5], 3: [0, 4, 5], 4: [0, 1, 3], 5: [0, 1, 2, 3]}`

Smallest vertex is `2: [1, 5]` so you take the 2,1 point and remove the vertex.

You then remove all versions of 2,1. (if its a vertex, remove it all)

This leaves you with:

`{0: [3, 4, 5], 3: [0, 4, 5], 4: [0, 3], 5: [0, 3]}` This is 1 match

Repeat logic(4,0) and you get: This is match 2

`{3: [5], 5: [3]}`

Finally repeat and you get your match 3.

I am assuming this is based off an algorithm but I do not know which one.

This is incredibly fast compared to my first solution of creating all the options for matches and then seeing which version was the largest
Thanks

Comment: How many compatible pairs do you get the following? I looked at your algo and get 15 pairs, but another algo finds 16. data =

Comment: {0: [2], 2: [0, 36], 1: [46], 46: [1, 16, 34], 36: [2, 8, 11, 41], 4: [34], 34: [4, 32, 37, 46], 5: [10, 15, 18, 23, 31, 35], 10: [5, 20, 24, 38], 15: [5], 18: [5], 23: [5, 9, 14, 17, 28], 31: [5, 21], 35: [5, 30], 6: [21], 21: [6, 17, 22, 31], 7: [40, 43], 40: [7, 26], 43: [7, 11], 8: [36], 9: [23], 20: [10, 42], 24: [10, 19], 38: [10, 17, 22], 11: [25, 36, 43], 25: [11, 14], 14: [23, 25], 16: [30, 46], 30: [16, 35], 17: [21, 23, 26, 38], 26: [17, 19, 40], 19: [24, 26, 29], 29: [19], 42: [20, 41], 22: [21, 38], 28: [23], 32: [34], 37: [34], 41: [36, 42]}

Comment: My algo gives 16 matches. what was the algo you compared it to?

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm tries to pick the maximum pairs from input using an iterative approach and usually comes within one pair of a more exhaustive search pattern on randomised data, but takes a fraction of the time to run

```py
compats = [{0: [3, 4, 5], 1: [2, 4, 5], 2: [1, 5], 3: [0, 4, 5], 4: [0, 1, 3], 5: [0, 1, 2, 3]},
           {0: [4, 1], 1: [4, 0], 2: [4], 3: [4], 4: [0, 1, 2, 3]}]
def _check(compat):
    """Check compatibilities are mutual."""
    compat2 = {k:set(v) for k, v in compat.items()}
    for p0, comp in compat2.items():
        for p1 in comp:
            assert p0 in compat2[p1], \
                f"{p0} compat with {p1} but {p1} not compat with {p0}?"
    every_item = set()
    for v in compat2.values():
        every_item |= v
    diffs = set(compat).symmetric_difference(every_item)
    assert not diffs, f"compat inner list items != compat keys: {diffs}"

def most_matched2(compat: Dict[int, List[int]]) -> Optional[List[Tuple[int, int]]]:
    """Match the most of the compatible people, iterably."""
    def reorder(c_list: List[Tuple[Any, List[Any]]]) -> List[Tuple[Any, Any]]:
        """
        Reorder compatibles; most compat first, their individual compatibilities
        sorted least compat first.

        ( reorder([(0, [4, 1]), (1, [4, 0]), (2, [4]), (3, [4]), (4, [0, 1, 2, 3])])
            == [(4, [3, 2, 1, 0]), (0, [1, 4]), (1, [0, 4]), (2, [4]), (3, [4])] )
        """
        # sort most number of compatible first
        c_list.sort(key=lambda x:(-len(x[1]), x))
        # sort compatibles least compatible first
        order = [x[0] for x in c_list]
        for person, comp in c_list:
            #print(person, comp)
            comp.sort(key=lambda x:-order.index(x))
        return c_list

    c = [(k, list(v)) for k, v in compat.items()]
    matches = set()
    while c:
        c = reorder(c)
        p0, p1 = c[0][0], c[0][1][0]
        matches.add(tuple(sorted((p0, p1))))
        p0p1_set = {p0, p1}
        c = [(p, remain) for p, comp in c
             if p not in p0p1_set and (remain := list(set(comp) - p0p1_set))]

    return sorted(matches)


for compat in compats:
    _check(compat)
    print(most_matched2(compat)) 
print()

# %% test gen
from itertools import combinations
from random import sample, randint
from collections import defaultdict
from time import monotonic
import pandas as pd


def _test_gen(n, k):
    possibles = list(set(c) for c in combinations(range(n), 2))
    if type(k) in {int, float}:
        k = int(min(k, len(possibles)))
    pairs = []
    while len(pairs) < k and possibles:
        p = possibles.pop(randint(0, len(possibles) - 1))
        pairs.append(p)
        if randint(0, 1):
            possibles = [x for x in possibles if not p.intersection(x)]
    compatibles = sorted(tuple(sorted(comp)) for comp in pairs)
    data = defaultdict(set)
    for p1, p2 in compatibles:
        data[p1].add(p2)
        data[p2].add(p1)
    data = {key: sorted(val - {key}) for key, val in data.items()}
    return data, [sorted(x) for x in pairs]

compat, pairs = _test_gen(4, 3)

print("\n## Random tests.")
for n, k in [(4, 5), (8, 5), (8, 5), (20, 40)]:
    compat, pairs = _test_gen(n, k)
    _check(compat)
    print(ans1 := most_matched2(compat))
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I needed exact:) Good for future use though